What does a history teacher at school ask a student to prepare by the next lesson? A report, a paper, a presentation or what?
For example, on the topic of "ancient Egyptian culture", "the life of Alexander the Great", "reasons of the Second World War" or something else. That is, the student looks for the information (writes it down if the teacher asked him to do it in written form). Then, the next history lesson, he tells the class what he has prepared.
Update:
I mean a personal assignment for some student besides his usual homework which is given to all class. And that student must tell his personal assignment to all other students in his class at the next lesson.

In my schooldays, if a history teacher asked me to 'prepare' (just that) for the next lesson, they meant that I should read the relevant chapter or section of the text-book, and thus be prepared for the lesson. You didn't have to  tell the class, but you could get into trouble (or look ridiculous) if you were revealed to be ignorant during the lesson.

This isn’t a question about English so much as a question about the behavior of teachers. Some ask for [written] reports, others for [oral] presentations. Still others ask for intricate, finely crafted scale models.

@MichaelHarvey I tried to explain it in more detail. Take a look at my update please. Did the question become clearer now?

In English, we generally write assignments, presentations, papers or essays. Not "prepare them".

Depends on what the teacher wants.  If she wants a written report, then "report".  If she wants the student to make a presentation to the class then "presentation". She might also ask for "notes" or "an essay", or "a mindmap" or "a poster" or any other way of presenting learning.
There is also a range of dialect differences.  US universities talk about "term papers", but in the UK, a "paper" normally presents original research, not an assigned task.

You wrote: "If she wants a written report, then "report". If she wants the student to make a presentation to the class then "presentation"." But then what's the difference between the report and the presentation in the given context? Thanks.

reports contain information about something (it might be spoken or written), but are necessarily presented.  A presentation would (usually) involve some sort of slideshow.

a term paper or paper is supposed to be original.

I thought a term paper is an assigned task.

A term paper can present the student-author's take on a topic of their own choosing and would be "original" in that sense, although not in the sense "self-initiated". A term paper can also be a survey of existing research.
